# Fetching the HTML text from a TextArea

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a `TextArea` that has last line

```
</strong> Esplanade Concert Hall <strong>MRT:</strong>
```

I need to get the last line text same as is.

I'm using this function to get it:

```
textarea.mx_internal::getTextField().getLineText(lastlineIndex-2)
```

But the value returned is plain text, I need the value with the `HTML` formatting, so that I could use the same string for some other string operations.

I need it because in `HTML` I need to

```
content.split(lastlineText);
```

and `content` holds `HTML` text.

Comment: Do you need to set htmlText to true?

Comment: The htmltext is coming up properly in the textarea. i need the last line of the textarea with the html formatting for string operations.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible because textfield not supported strong tag. Strong tag removed from textarea htmltext. But you can use RegEx. Split last line as words and create pattern. See down (maybe you modify code for yourself):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               creationComplete="application_creationCompleteHandler(event)"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            protected var str:String = "";

            protected function application_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                str = 'ActionScript 3 (AS3) is the open source object oriented programming (OOP) language of the Adobe <strong>Flash</strong> and <b>AIR</b> Platforms.';

                textarea.addEventListener("htmlTextChanged", textarea_changeHandler, false, 0, true);
                textarea.htmlText = str;
            }

            protected function textarea_changeHandler(event:Event):void
            {
                var allLines:Number = textarea.mx_internal::getTextField().numLines;
                var line:String = textarea.mx_internal::getTextField().getLineText(allLines-1); 

                var arr:Array = line.match(/\w+[.!?]?/gi);

                var pattern:String = "";

                var i:uint = 0;
                var l:uint = arr.length;

                for ( ; i<l; i++)
                {
                    pattern += "(<[^</]+?>)?\\s*" +  arr[i] + "\\s*(<[^<]+?>)?" + "\\s*";
                }

                var regex:RegExp = new RegExp(pattern, "gi");

                trace( str.match(regex) );

            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <mx:TextArea id="textarea" width="280" height="100" x="100"/>

</s:Application>
```